# How can we see the list of files in dynamic library (.so)

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a way to view the list of object files in dynamic library (.so) like static library below.

```
ar -t llibexample.a
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command Line to see the contents Shared Object Module(lib\*.so)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656077/command-line-to-see-the-contents-shared-object-modulelib-so)

Comment: I want to see the .o files.Do we have any command for dynamic library to check the same.

Comment: Dynamic library does not contain any object files. Some information regarding origination of library content probably  can be found at debug symbols.